Choice of $\lambda,\mu,\nu$ values to determine the parametric equation of the line
Let's consider a Cartesian monometric orthogonal reference system in space $S$. Let's consider the following plane:
$$\pi:4x+2y+3z=0$$After choosing a point $P$ not belonging to the plane $\pi$, then:
$(1)$ determine a line $r$ passing through the point $P$ and parallel to the plane $\pi$.
What have I done: I can choose infinitely many points $P$ not belonging to the plane $\pi$.
To simplify calculations, let's take $P=(1,0,0)$, so $4 \cdot 1 + 2 \cdot 0 + 3 \cdot 0\neq 0$, and thus $P \not\in \pi$.
There are infinitely many lines passing through point $P$ and parallel to the plane $\pi$. Let's write the parametric equation of the line:
$$r:\begin{cases}
x = x_0 + \lambda \rho \\
y = y_0 + \mu \rho \\
z = z_0 + \nu \rho
\end{cases}$$ Imposing passage through point $P$:
$$r:\begin{cases}
x = 1 + \lambda \rho \\
y = \mu \rho \\
z = \nu \rho
\end{cases}$$Imposing the condition of parallelism between the line and the plane:
$$a\lambda + b\mu + c\nu = 0 \Rightarrow 4\lambda+2\mu+3\nu=0$$
In the solution it says: choose the values $$\lambda = 1, \mu = −2$$ so the equation becomes $\nu = 0$, therefore the parametric equation of the line is:
$$r:\begin{cases}
x = 1 + \rho \\
y = -2\rho \\
z = 0
\end{cases}$$
My doubt is : I think the variables can take on any value because the equation admits $\infty$ solutions, right?

Is there a reason why these exactly values are chosen in this case?
Could I also choose the values of $\mu$ and $\nu$ and obtain $\lambda$? Or do I have to do it exactly this way?

I'll give you an example: I had chosen $\mu = -2$ and $\nu = 3$ then the parametric equation of the line would have been:
$$r:\begin{cases}
x = 1 -\frac{5}{4}\rho \\
y = -2\rho \\
z = 3\rho
\end{cases}$$
Is this also a correct solution or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance to anyone who wants to help me :)

Yes, it's correct. In fact, the choice of parameters are simply rotating the line around in any of the directions parallel to the plane. You may find this simulation on desmos useful to convince yourself:
https://www.desmos.com/3d/3ctbdvllp8
The solutions in this case were chosen because it was the most obvious relation between the three. (as it is easy to see that if you set the final parameter to be zero, there is an easy relation between the other two parameters). But obviously, it is not the only possible solution, as you have correctly deduced, there are infinitely many lines parallel to the plane .

Would it have been possible to approach this exercise in another way? I don't want you to write me the whole method , just whether it was possible or not, and whether this method is the fastest or not. A thousand thanks :) @J.D

@Pizza another way you could have done this is seen right away that $ y=-2x,z=0$ is a line contained completely within the plane , then translate the line so P lies on the translated line, which will be parallel to the plane.
